# Is it possible to exit to the terminal from an interactively run loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, console, exit

First of all let me say sorry that I was unable to condense this problem any further. It's a very simple concept but I found it very difficult to word in a way that could be universally understood. Many of the words I use below get tossed around so carelessly you have to set up a whole scenario to use them intelligibly.

I'm running a game script in interactive mode so that if I break it with an exception I can still interact with the game environment (classes, objects and variables).

myScript.py:

```
def game():
  print("")
  print("Starting game loop...")
  display=0
  while True:
    print(display)
    command = input("Press ENTER to proceed...")

game()
```

But every time I update the script I have to break the loop with `break` by specifying 'console' at the user prompt, and then call `exit()` at the console before returning to the terminal where I can then run the script fresh.

So I added these lines to the game loop:

```
  if command.lower() == "console":
    print("")
    break
  elif command.lower() == "terminal"
    #exit() throws an exception
    #`import sys` nl `sys.exit()` throws an exception
  else:
    display+=1
    print("")
    print("Continuing game loop...")
```

Output:

```
user@user-VirtualBox-Ubuntu:~$ python3 -i /home/username/scripts/myScript.py

Starting game loop...
0
Press ENTER to proceed, enter 'console' to halt and 'terminal' to leave...

Continuing game loop...
1
Press ENTER to proceed, enter 'console' to halt and 'terminal' to leave...

Continuing game loop...
2
Press ENTER to proceed, enter 'console' to halt and 'terminal' to leave...

Continuing game loop...
3
Press ENTER to proceed, enter 'console' to halt and 'terminal' to leave... console

>>>
```

As you can see above, I have prepared an elif circumstance for skipping a step and going straight to the terminal, where I should then be able to press UP twice to find `clear` and then UP twice again to find my interactive script call line. But, the only relevant solution I could find on SO is the one you can see in my `myScript.py` file involving the import of `sys`, which throws an error.

So, is it possible to produce the behavior of `exit()` (when typed from the command line) from a script without generating exceptions?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want an exception? I'd just hit `Ctrl-C Ctrl-D`, which would involve a KeyboardInterrupt exception, but would take about a second to do.

Comment: I guess I just feel like a proper script shouldn't generate exceptions on the way out :/... But maybe I just need more experience.

Comment: You're definitely taking that too seriously if you're worried about the `SystemExit` exception generated by `sys.exit()`, especially considering that the behavior you want to replicate is implemented by throwing that very exception.

Comment: See I didn't know that. If you wanted to do an answer talking about that in some detail I'd appreciate it.